# Where are the built in editors stored?

Tags: tabulator

I just want to copy the checkbox editor and make a custom editor that has a gray checkmark to differentiate in my table which checkboxes are editable (default green) and which aren't (in gray).

I figured I could just copy the existing editor and change the color but I don't know where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator 4.9 :

tabulator-master/dist/js/tabulator.js:17201

Answer (score 0):

All the editors can be found in the `/src/js/modules/Edit/defaults/editors` folder.

If you are looking specifically for an example of a checkbox editor, then the source for that particular editor can be found [Here](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/master/src/js/modules/Edit/defaults/editors/tickCross.js)